# Is there a R function to estimate the law of a sample?

Tags: r, sample

Starting from a given sample, is it possible to estimate (roughly) automatically what kind of law the variable inducing this sample seems to follow?

Comment: You can estimate the kernel density from a sample using the density() function

Comment: If Marco's answer is going in the right direction (I wasn't sure what you meant by law) you may be able to Kolmogorov-Smirnov test versus various distributions and see which one has the best fit.

Comment: Yes, it is going in the right direction. I have been asking someone who is better than me in statistics, and he says when I said law, I was meaning distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial approach is to use likelihood based estimation and compare the fit among various family of parametric distributions.

You can use function $\verb+MASS::fitdistr()+$ to fit one of:
"beta","cauchy","chi-squared","exponential","fisher","gamma","geometric","log-normal","logistic","negative","binomial","normal","Poisson","t" and "weibull".

For more options (censored distribution and MDE based estimation) you can turn to 
the [$\verb+fitdistrplus+$](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/) package

both approach can be easily automated, tough MDE seems more suited than likelihood loss.